# Two lists with different length, but return nothing while checking the different element

Tags: python, list, set, difference

I have two lists in the format `['apple','orange', ...]`.

```
len(list1) = 714 
len(list2) = 715
```

I want to check the difference between these two lists, so I use:

```
set(list2) - set(list1)
```

but I get:

```
set([])
```

By the way:

```
len(set(list1)) == len(list1)
len(set(list2)) == len(list2)
```

Does anyone know why there is no difference?

Comment: Do you have a smaller reproducible copy of the two lists?

Comment: One of those things must be false...

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @gladys0313: Can you give us an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can put into our copies of Python to see what you're seeing?

Comment: Can you give example lists for which this occurs, preferable shorter than 700+ items?

Comment: Thank you all, I finally found it

Comment: @gladys0313 Could you please post the answer?

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes I have posted it

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if two lists are different, you can use `set(list1)-set(list2)` to find the difference. The only think you should pay attention to is the *sequence of subtraction*. If `len(list1)>len(list2)`, then you should do `set(list1)-set(list2)`, otherwise you will get `set([])`

Comment: This is not really an answer, you should edit this into your question

Comment: Or is it so that you made a typo in the question itself, since the question subtracts the smaller set from the larger set?